# OctoberCMS extend backend controller [Form Behavior] to override create, update actions?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

i am using OctoberCMS for a project and in the backend, i want to know how to override the create, update, delete actions in the controller.

Actually, i developed a custom form widget which is a full page calender and i want to use the deffered binding as the model i am trying to save this calender is not exists at the point of creation.

So, any help regarding "Deffered Binding" or "Controller Actions Override" would be appreciated.

I refered the documenation but its not much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Anybody? Anybody? Anybody?

Comment: Post code of your controller and model and what are you trying to differ bind ?

Comment: I found solution, Thanks for having look :)

Comment: Please answer your solution as a new answer so that it can help future readers if they stuck in a same situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You can use your own logic for the create, update or preview action method in the controller, then optionally call the Form behavior parent method

check this link:
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#overriding-action